# Obstacle Avoidance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to implement obstacle avoidance within steering behaviors for a university project.

When I run the project, the AI agent seems to get confused and 'spaz' out moving from left to right very quickly and still doesn't avoid obstacles correctly.

I'm trying to cast a box in front of the agent so that when that box collides with an obstacle, it'll steer away from it and continue to move wander.

Here is the code for the Obstacle Avoidance

```
    public Vector3 ObstalceAvoidance()
    {
        //Cast a ray from the centre of the agent, in it's forward direction
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);

        //Name a raycastHit
        RaycastHit hitInfo;

        //Set avoidanceForce to ZERO for all axis
        Vector3 avoidanceForce = Vector3.zero;

        //Calculate the 'Avoidance Force'
        if(Physics.BoxCast(transform.forward, new Vector3(2.5f, 2.5f, 20.0f), transform.forward, out hitInfo, transform.rotation, maxDistance))
        {
            if(Vector3.Angle(hitInfo.normal, transform.up) > floorAngle)
            {
                //Reflect the Vector
                avoidanceForce = Vector3.Reflect(agent.velocity, hitInfo.normal);

                //Calculate the dot product between the Force and Velocity
                if (Vector3.Dot(avoidanceForce, agent.velocity) < -0.9f)
                {
                    //Transform Right
                    avoidanceForce = transform.right;
                }
            }
        }

        if(avoidanceForce != Vector3.zero)
        {
            //Calculate desired velocity
            desiredVelocity = (avoidanceForce).normalized * agent.maxSpeed;

            //Calculate the steering Force
            steeringForce = desiredVelocity - agent.velocity;
            oldSteeringForce = steeringForce;
            forceTimer = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            steeringForce = Vector3.zero;
        }
        return steeringForce;
    }
```

Comment: What's your "agent" ? If it's a NavMeshAgent, obstacle avoidance is builtin

Comment: As part of the module at uni, we have to implement all of the AI techniques ourselves, rather than using Unity's built in functions.

Comment: Does your vehicle have a collider on it? If it does, maybe the boxcast hitinfo is always returning the vehicle itself so the vehicle is constantly trying to dodge itself?